# what is the equivalent of du -s --si * in a Solaris box?

Tags: solaris, disk-usage

I have a Solaris box that is blowing up right now because a disk is very close to filling up.  I need to know what subdirectory on that disk is hogging up the space, but Solaris doesn't like `du -s --si *`.  What do I do?

Comment: Just use du -s | sort -n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`du -s` command should run under Solaris as well as any decent unix compliant OS. Whereas `si` or humanly readable output (in 1000s not 1024s) is an option under gnu version of this command, which comes on many, if not all Linux distributions.

`du -s` command should work. If it is not working, you need to provide any errors you are getting. If you think it is hanging, taking too much time, you might have too many files in the directory and its subdirectories and the code is taking time to collect all the data necessary. It  is not really an error.

Answer (score 2):

On Solaris 11, the equivalent would be:

```
gdu -s --si *
```

Solaris 11 has many GNU utilities available, prepended with a `g` - `gtar`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

As usual on UNIX, the solution is found via checking the man pages.

And 30 seconds after calling `man du`, you should have found the solution:

`du -sh`